# Thread-locking a structure in read only mode (C11 stdatomic)

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, mutex, atomic

I've created a mutex-like lock function with stdatomic that basically does

```
do atomic_store(&zero, 0);
while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&mystructure->address, &zero, threadlocal_address));
atomic_fetch_add(&structure->locklevel, 1);
```

and another unlock function that decrements locklevel and sets the address back to zero ONLY IF locklevel==0 (this allows locking before calling a function which calls another lock, allowing it to still remain locked)

this works fine for RW locking, but I also wanted to make a R-lock function (structure can be read by multiple functions, but trying to write it [calling a RW-lock] will put it to wait) and I tried by simply using a public address instead of a threadlocal one.

The problem with this approach is it would lead to starvation of RW operations if many threads call R-lock in a loop (as locklevel would never [or hardly ever] get to zero)... any ideas?

Comment: Writer starvation is a well-explored problem, but not easily solved without some idea of the expected characteristics of the resulting system. Have you given thought to reader vs. writer ratio? The length of read and write operations? There are many other factors and several different solutions besides RW locks as well. Have you considered making your data copy-on-write, for example?

Comment: @DarkFalcon my structure contains pointers to dynamically allocated memory, so that approach woudn't work for me

Comment: Sure it could. Copy everything deeply or keep a counter for how many references a given external pointer has. In any case, you're going to have to answer the other questions if you want help choosing an approach.

Comment: @DarkFalcon yeah but the allocated memory array could possibly be very long, and malloc is by itself an expensive operation

Comment: Unless you're changing it only once every 5 minutes or something, in which case maybe cost doesn't matter much. *You still need to specify the performance characteristics of your system.*

Comment: @DarkFalcon the structure is a basically just a string, which stores, other than the pointer to the string itself, (and the previously cited lock-level and lock-address) also the current string size. The header file it's declared in provides basic reading-writing-comparing-fileIO operations

Comment: @DarkFalcon also, the header is a simple library I published, so it's up to the user to decide the frequency of read operations over write operations

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use priority for read-write operations. I am assuming that rw/read ratio is low in your system. Implement a basic queue for rw requests and while there is a rw request waiting in the queue, prevent read requests to acquire the lock. After current read requests completed, acquire lock for rw and wait for it to complete. So as long as there is a rw request waiting in the queue or currently running, block read requests. When rw thread unlocks and there is no more rw requests waiting in the queue allow read requests to acquire lock.

You may also need to use condition variables and signaling them depending on your implementation.